# How to optimize mysql query with join

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, innodb

```
SELECT
    `bulletins`.`id`,
    `category_id`,
    `orders_bulletins`.`order_id` AS `pivot_order_id`,
    `orders_bulletins`.`bulletin_id` AS `pivot_bulletin_id`
FROM
    `bulletins`
INNER JOIN `orders_bulletins` ON `bulletins`.`id` = `orders_bulletins`.`bulletin_id`
WHERE
    `orders_bulletins`.`order_id` = 2 AND(`done` = 0 AND `error` = 0)
```

Bulletins table have ~35 millon rows

indexes:

**bulletins:**

```
CREATE TABLE `bulletins` (
 `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `data` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL CHECK (json_valid(`data`)),
 `item_data` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT '0',
 `phone` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `done` bigint(20) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (coalesce(json_value(`item_data`,'$.id'),0)) VIRTUAL,
 `error` int(10) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (coalesce(json_value(`item_data`,'$.error.code'),0)) VIRTUAL,
 `time` bigint(20) unsigned GENERATED ALWAYS AS (json_value(`data`,'$.time')) VIRTUAL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `phone` (`phone`),
 KEY `id` (`phone`,`id`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `done` (`done`,`error`,`time`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2047904069 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED
```

**orders_bulletins:**

```
CREATE TABLE `orders_bulletins` (
 `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `order_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `bulletin_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `order_id` (`order_id`,`bulletin_id`),
 KEY `bulletin_id` (`bulletin_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=82218220 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

The query above takes about 90 mins - this is not acceptable for sure :) Maybe I can somehow speed up it?

**EXPLAIN:**
[image]

Comment: Replace screenshots with complete CREATE TABLE scripts.

Comment: My suggestion: please create index on the data field "error" . After that please see whether the speed can be improved in running your SQL

Comment: @KenLee One table copy may use only one index. Why you decide that the index by `error` is more useful than all another existing indices?

Comment: mysql supports multiple indexes on a single table (please use "create index error on [table_name] (error)" to create the additional index. (I suggest you to create one ADDITIONAL index, not to replace your current index)

Comment: replaced screenshots

Comment: I will try index for error, but it takes about 6 hours, I tried to create test tables with part of data but mysql choosing first select from bulletins with index 'done' and then join instead of real tables - it first select from orders_bulletins as I show on screenshot

Comment: MySQL (at least the last time I checked) is able to use only 1 index per table - so even if you have multiple indexes in the table it will use only 1 of them. But it can choose different index for different queries. PostgreSQL can use more than 1 index per table if the optimizer decides it will speed up the query. You can speed up your JOIN if you move the filters from WHERE clause inside the JOIN - by replacing the table name with a subquery. You may also change the "done" index to exclude "time" - or add new index over "error", "done" and "order_id" columns.

Comment: @IVOGELOV maybe then add id to 'done' index if it uses PRIMARY?

Comment: @KenLee - based on the `WHERE` clause and the existence of `INDEX(done, error, ...)`, adding `INDEX(error)` will _not_ help.

Comment: In _rare_ cases, MySQL will use two indexes (cf "index merge").  However, with `AND`, it is always better to have a composite query, such as (`done`,`error`,`time`).

Comment: @rst630 - Which is more selective?  `order_id=2` or `done=0 and error=0`?  (The answer may lead to a performance solution.)

Comment: @RickJames `order_id=2` ~2 millions, `done=0 and error=0` ~25 millions

Comment: @rst630 - Which table is `category_id` in??

Comment: @RickJames bulletins

Answer (score 0):

It will take a long time.  Here's what is happening.  And it appears to be optimal:

1. Go through the BTree for UNIQUE KEY `order_id` (`order_id`,`bulletin_id`).  This is essentially a linear scan because of `order_id=2`.
2. That gives about 3M `bulletin_id` values.
3. For each of those, drill into the BTree for `bulletins` to look for the row.
4. Check `done=0 and error=0`.
5. If the check passes, retrieve `category_id` (the last of the 4 columns needed)

Step 3 is probably the slowest part.  It could involve up to 2M disk reads, depending on how randomly distributed the values are.  At worst, that is about 32GB being read (and/or reread) into memory.  (At best all the blocks are already cached and there is no I/O.)

It sounds like you have a spinning disk (HDD), not SSD?

How much RAM do you have?  More RAM might help.  What is the setting of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  If it is not as big as it should be, raise it to about 70% of RAM.

Since you have NVMe SSD, I can't blame the slowness on I/O.  So...  I don't know how much time it takes to extract `done` and `error` from the json string in step 4.

If the query is CPU-bound and not I/O-bound, then the extraction is the problem.  Change from `VIRTUAL` to `STORED` for those two columns and change the datatypes to the smallest that will work, perhaps `TINYINT`.  Caution:  It may take hours to do the `ALTER`.

(Note:  Only 1 CPU core will be used for the query.)

Since it is not currently using the index, let's try to trick it into using a "covering" index:  `INDEX(done, error, category_id, id)`.  If that index is not automatically used, add an index 'hint'.

Comment: innodb_buffer_pool_size 14G, total ram is 32gb, but bulletins table 200GB and it will just bigger in the future - much bigger. Disk NVMe ssd

Comment: I think indexed virtual column is the same as stored - does't it?

Comment: why `category_id` must be in index? Im not doing queries with `where category_id`. CPU load not huge. `dstat -d` shows ~5mb/s read during this query works - don't know why it so slow read

Comment: A "covering" index is one that contains all the columns needed _anywhere_ in the query.  That lets the work be done entirely in the index's BTree.  (No guarantees that it will solve the problem.)